# Is a finite union of bounded sets bounded in any metrical space?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

In any metrical space $(M,d_M)$, consider $n$ bounded subsets $S_i\subset M$. Then, is $\cup_i^nS_i$ bounded? If so, why?

Comment: My idea is to show that $diam(M)<\infty$ this is easy if the distance between two subsets is finite. The problem is that I am not sure if this distance is finite.

Comment: What is your definition of bounded?

Comment: my definition of bounded is that $diam(M)<\infty$, that is $diam(S)=sup\{d(x,y); x,y\in S\}$.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Since each $S_j$ is bounded, there exists a point $p_j$ such that $S_j\subset B(p_j,r_j)$. Now take $p=p_1$, $r=\max\{r_1,\ldots,r_n\}+\max_j\{d(p_1,p_j)\}$. If $x\in S_j$, then
$$
d(x,p)\leq d(x,p_j)+d(p_j,p_1)\leq r_j+d(p_j,p_1)\leq r.
$$
So $x\in B(p,r)$, and this shows that $S_j\subset B(p,r)$ for all $j$. Thus 
$$
\bigcup_j S_j\subset B(p,r).
$$

Comment: Do you mean to say 'there exists a point $p_j$ and there exists $r_j$ such that...'? I didn't see how you introduced the $r_j$'s.

Comment: Also, does $p_j$ have to be in $S_j$?

Comment: To your first question, yes; to your second question, no.

Comment: @MartinArgerami - What does the notation "max$_{j}${}" mean? I am not familiar with it.

Comment: $\max_j\{a_j\}=\max\{a_1,\ldots,a_n\}$.

Answer (score 6):

Of course. A set is $S$ bounded iff for every $p$ in the space there is some $r_S$ such that $S \subset B(p,r_S)$. For finite unions we take the maximum of the $r_S$ in the union.

Comment: So if I understand this correct, the distance between two bounded subsets cannot be infinitely large?

Comment: That's not really the definition of bounded, but a provable property about boundedness (that there is an $r$ for every $p$.)

Comment: I know, that's why I wrote iff

Comment: @Godisemo indeed.

Answer (score 0):

In the comments you say that your definition of *bounded* $S$ is
$$
\mathrm{diam}(S) < +\infty.
$$

You want to prove that if $S$ is bounded and $x\in M$ is any point, then 
$$
  \sup_{y\in S} d(x,y) < +\infty
$$
(use triangular inequality) and then you can easily prove this last inequality for the finite union of bounded sets.